# Analog of self-conjugate representation of symmetric group for Hecke algebra

Tags: symmetric-groups, hecke-algebras

Consider a symmetric group $S_n$. It is generated by generators $\sigma_1\dotsc\sigma_{n-1}$ that satisfy the following relations:

1. Square relations: $\sigma_k^2=1,\qquad k=1\ldots n-1$.
2. Braid relations: $\sigma_k\sigma_{k+1}\sigma_k=\sigma_{k+1}\sigma_k\sigma_{k+1},\qquad k=1\ldots n-2$.

It is well-known that there exist certain representations of $S_n$, for which a character of any product of an *odd*  number of $\sigma$'s vanishes. Actually, for any representation $T$ a direct sum of $T$ and $T\otimes \operatorname{sign}$, where $\operatorname{sign}$ is a 1-dimensional sign representation, will have this property. There even exist "self-conjugate" irreducible representations, which satisfy $T=T\otimes \operatorname{sign}$, and they by themselves possess this property.

Now to the question. I'd like to consider a Hecke algebra of $S_n$, which is generated by different generators $\bar{\sigma_1}\ldots\bar{\sigma}_{n-1}$ that satisfy perturbed square relations:

$\bar{\sigma}_k^2=1+\alpha\bar{\sigma}_k$ for some number $\alpha$

and braid relations which are similar to those of $S_n$.

It is known that every irreducible representation of $S_n$ can be deformed without changing its dimensionality to become a representation of the Hecke algebra.

My question is the following:

Do there exist representations of Hecke algebra possessing the above-mentioned property: a character of a product of any odd number of $\bar{\sigma}$'s vanishes?

Answer (score 3):

For most values of $\alpha$ the answer is no. The reason is that the eigenvalues of a generator $\bar\sigma_k$ have to satisfy $x^2=1+\alpha x$, and the two possibilities are $x=(\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+4})/2$. If there are $m_1$ with a plus sign and $m_2$ with a minus sign then for trace zero we have $(m_1+m_2)\alpha+(m_1-m_2)\sqrt{\alpha^2+4}=0$, so $(m_1-m_2)^2(\alpha^2+4)=(m_1+m_2)^2\alpha^2$, which gives $\alpha^2=\frac{(m_1-m_2)^2}{m_1m_2}$. So $\alpha^2$ has to be rational. Since $m_1+m_2$ takes a finite number of values for a given $n$, there are only a finite number of $\alpha$ for which the trace can be zero on some representation of the Hecke algebra of $S_n$. And then there are more conditions coming from odd length products of these generators.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I didn't think this way. Your method deals with $\bar{\sigma}$'s only and not with their products. Even a finite amount of $\alpha$'s can be good enough for me, so I guess I need to proceed further.

Comment: Given an irreducible representation of the symmetric group, you can work out how many $+1$ eigenvalues and how many $-1$ there are for $\sigma_k$, from the dimension and the trace. The multiplicities of the two eigenvalues of the corresponding generator of the Hecke algebra are the same, so you can work out the trace that way.